# Objective-C: Remove all files from directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, delete-file

Here is my method to remove a file from the temporary directory:

```
- (void)removeFileNamed:(NSString *)fileName
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
}
```

How can I change this code to remove EVERY file from the temporary directory (i.e. no parameter required)?

**EDIT**

The solution from the duplicate question solved the issue for me.

Comment: Have you considered / tried anything? What did it do wrong?

Comment: Maybe you could start with `- contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:`

Comment: And return `BOOL` and use that `error` parameter to report errors.

Answer (score 1):

E.g. by using a directory enumerator:

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDirectoryEnumerator* en = [fm enumeratorAtPath:path];    
NSError* err = nil;
BOOL res;

NSString* file;
while (file = [en nextObject]) {
    res = [fm removeItemAtPath:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:file] error:&err];
    if (!res && err) {
        NSLog(@"oops: %@", err);
    }
}
```

Comment: hello sir do u know how to music library item delete objective c

Comment: I'm not sure you are able to remove the music Item!

Comment: any other idea for hide audio file if this one select collection add then hide item